# How to extend gradle war task with dofirst/dolast

Tags: gradle, war

I need to extend the gradle war task with some doFirst and doLast commands to compile my sencha frontend in production state.

I know to extend a task I need to add task.doFirst {} but this is not working with war. I did some tests using other tasks like

```
clean {
    doFirst {
        println "test"
    }
}
```

This is working ... but with war it isn't

```
war {
    doFirst {
        println "test"
    }
}
```

My main idea was to remove `src/main/webapp` from the `from` list and execute sencha-cmd `sencha app build -c --destination $war/ production`

Comment: Your example (war task) works for me with Gradle 2.14.1

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate task for the sencha compilation with it's own inputs/outputs so Gradle can perform up-to-date checking (so it can be skipped if not necessary). You can then wire the task into the gradle [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) via [Task.dependsOn(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn%28java.lang.Object...%29)

```
task compileSencha(type:Exec) {
    inputs.dir 'src/main/sencha'
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/sencha"
    commandLine 'sencha', 'app', 'build', file('src/main/sencha').absolutePath, file("$buildDir/sencha").absolutePath
}

war {
   from "$buildDir/sencha"
   dependsOn compileSencha
}
```

Comment: ok thats great. But I need to place the sources in src/main/webapp otherwise the normal intellij debug is not providing the sources correctly. Therefore I have added exclude('**') to prevent the raw sources to be copied. Now after the `compileSencha` is finished I need to copy the `$buildDir/sencha` content to the war file

Comment: I'm not an intellij user but I hate putting generated files in src/main/webapp (or src/main/java etc). That could also mess with the compileSencha up to date checking and also source control (eg git). Better to keep it separate. Ideally intellij could use multiple source folders. Alternatively you can copy src/main/webapp and the compiled sencha resources into a folder under $buildDir (eg $buildDir/intellijWebapp) and point intellij to that folder instead of src/main/webapp

Comment: No under `src/main/webapp` the sources are located. Then `compileSencha` generates the minified files in `$buildDir/sencha` but I need to exclude the raw sources in `src/main/webapp` .. So the question is how to exclude `src/main/webapp` because `war { exclude("*") }` excludes everything ... also `from("$buildDir/sencha")` is then excluded

Comment: I personally hate excluding specific files. In my opinion, everything under src/main/webapp should be in the war. Perhaps you should put sencha resources under src/main/senchaResources rather than src/main/webapp. To keep your build clean, you should always selectively join folders together rather than exclude specific file patterns from one uber folder.